# grpc: protobuf cross-language code generation results in naming inconsistency

Tags: javascript, python, dart, protocol-buffers, grpc

I found that using snake_case in protobuf definition will have slightly different generated method/class names across different languages. The difference is in the casing if the protocol field name uses snake_case.

### Example

A regular `protoc` code-generation based on the following protocol

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package myservice;

service Myservice {
    rpc MyService(Request) returns (Reply) {}
}

message Request {
  bool my_foo = 1;
  bool my_bar = 2;
}

message Reply {
    bool is_succeeded = 1;
}
```

yields the following generated naming

#### Python

```sh
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I="${SRC_DIR}" --python_out="${DST_DIR}" --grpc_python_out=$DST_DIR --proto_path="${SRC_DIR}" my.proto
```

my_pb2_grpc.py

```py
# Generated by the gRPC Python protocol compiler plugin. DO NOT EDIT!
"""Client and server classes corresponding to protobuf-defined services."""
import grpc

import my_pb2 as my__pb2


class MyserviceStub(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    def __init__(self, channel):
        """Constructor.

        Args:
            channel: A grpc.Channel.
        """
        self.MyService = channel.unary_unary(
                '/myservice.Myservice/MyService',
                request_serializer=my__pb2.Request.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=my__pb2.Reply.FromString,
                )


class MyserviceServicer(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    def MyService(self, request, context):
        """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""
        context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED)
        context.set_details('Method not implemented!')
        raise NotImplementedError('Method not implemented!')


def add_MyserviceServicer_to_server(servicer, server):
    rpc_method_handlers = {
            'MyService': grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler(
                    servicer.MyService,
                    request_deserializer=my__pb2.Request.FromString,
                    response_serializer=my__pb2.Reply.SerializeToString,
            ),
    }
    generic_handler = grpc.method_handlers_generic_handler(
            'myservice.Myservice', rpc_method_handlers)
    server.add_generic_rpc_handlers((generic_handler,))


 # This class is part of an EXPERIMENTAL API.
class Myservice(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    @staticmethod
    def MyService(request,
            target,
            options=(),
            channel_credentials=None,
            call_credentials=None,
            insecure=False,
            compression=None,
            wait_for_ready=None,
            timeout=None,
            metadata=None):
        return grpc.experimental.unary_unary(request, target, '/myservice.Myservice/MyService',
            my__pb2.Request.SerializeToString,
            my__pb2.Reply.FromString,
            options, channel_credentials,
            insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)
```

my_pb2.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: my.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='my.proto',
  package='myservice',
  syntax='proto3',
  serialized_options=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  serialized_pb=b'\n\x08my.proto\x12\tmyservice\")\n\x07Request\x12\x0e\n\x06my_foo\x18\x01 \x01(\x08\x12\x0e\n\x06my_bar\x18\x02 \x01(\x08\"\x1d\n\x05Reply\x12\x14\n\x0cis_succeeded\x18\x01 \x01(\x08\x32@\n\tMyservice\x12\x33\n\tMyService\x12\x12.myservice.Request\x1a\x10.myservice.Reply\"\x00\x62\x06proto3'
)




_REQUEST = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Request',
  full_name='myservice.Request',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='my_foo', full_name='myservice.Request.my_foo', index=0,
      number=1, type=8, cpp_type=7, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=False,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='my_bar', full_name='myservice.Request.my_bar', index=1,
      number=2, type=8, cpp_type=7, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=False,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto3',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=23,
  serialized_end=64,
)


_REPLY = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Reply',
  full_name='myservice.Reply',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='is_succeeded', full_name='myservice.Reply.is_succeeded', index=0,
      number=1, type=8, cpp_type=7, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=False,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto3',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=66,
  serialized_end=95,
)

DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Request'] = _REQUEST
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Reply'] = _REPLY
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

Request = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Request', (_message.Message,), {
  'DESCRIPTOR' : _REQUEST,
  '__module__' : 'my_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:myservice.Request)
  })
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Request)

Reply = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Reply', (_message.Message,), {
  'DESCRIPTOR' : _REPLY,
  '__module__' : 'my_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:myservice.Reply)
  })
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Reply)



_MYSERVICE = _descriptor.ServiceDescriptor(
  name='Myservice',
  full_name='myservice.Myservice',
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  index=0,
  serialized_options=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  serialized_start=97,
  serialized_end=161,
  methods=[
  _descriptor.MethodDescriptor(
    name='MyService',
    full_name='myservice.Myservice.MyService',
    index=0,
    containing_service=None,
    input_type=_REQUEST,
    output_type=_REPLY,
    serialized_options=None,
    create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  ),
])
_sym_db.RegisterServiceDescriptor(_MYSERVICE)

DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name['Myservice'] = _MYSERVICE

# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

#### Node.js

With `grpc-node` the result looks like this

```sh
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:"${DST_DIR}" --grpc_out=grpc_js:"${DST_DIR}" --proto_path="${SRC_DIR}" my.proto
```

my_grpc_pb.js

```js
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!

'use strict';
var grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
var my_pb = require('./my_pb.js');

function serialize_myservice_Reply(arg) {
  if (!(arg instanceof my_pb.Reply)) {
    throw new Error('Expected argument of type myservice.Reply');
  }
  return Buffer.from(arg.serializeBinary());
}

function deserialize_myservice_Reply(buffer_arg) {
  return my_pb.Reply.deserializeBinary(new Uint8Array(buffer_arg));
}

function serialize_myservice_Request(arg) {
  if (!(arg instanceof my_pb.Request)) {
    throw new Error('Expected argument of type myservice.Request');
  }
  return Buffer.from(arg.serializeBinary());
}

function deserialize_myservice_Request(buffer_arg) {
  return my_pb.Request.deserializeBinary(new Uint8Array(buffer_arg));
}


var MyserviceService = exports.MyserviceService = {
  myService: {
    path: '/myservice.Myservice/MyService',
    requestStream: false,
    responseStream: false,
    requestType: my_pb.Request,
    responseType: my_pb.Reply,
    requestSerialize: serialize_myservice_Request,
    requestDeserialize: deserialize_myservice_Request,
    responseSerialize: serialize_myservice_Reply,
    responseDeserialize: deserialize_myservice_Reply,
  },
};

exports.MyserviceClient = grpc.makeGenericClientConstructor(MyserviceService);
```

my_pb.js

```js
// source: my.proto
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @enhanceable
 * @suppress {missingRequire} reports error on implicit type usages.
 * @suppress {messageConventions} JS Compiler reports an error if a variable or
 *     field starts with 'MSG_' and isn't a translatable message.
 * @public
 */
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck

var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global = Function('return this')();

goog.exportSymbol('proto.myservice.Reply', null, global);
goog.exportSymbol('proto.myservice.Request', null, global);
/**
 * Generated by JsPbCodeGenerator.
 * @param {Array=} opt_data Optional initial data array, typically from a
 * server response, or constructed directly in Javascript. The array is used
 * in place and becomes part of the constructed object. It is not cloned.
 * If no data is provided, the constructed object will be empty, but still
 * valid.
 * @extends {jspb.Message}
 * @constructor
 */
proto.myservice.Request = function(opt_data) {
  jspb.Message.initialize(this, opt_data, 0, -1, null, null);
};
goog.inherits(proto.myservice.Request, jspb.Message);
if (goog.DEBUG && !COMPILED) {
  /**
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  proto.myservice.Request.displayName = 'proto.myservice.Request';
}
/**
 * Generated by JsPbCodeGenerator.
 * @param {Array=} opt_data Optional initial data array, typically from a
 * server response, or constructed directly in Javascript. The array is used
 * in place and becomes part of the constructed object. It is not cloned.
 * If no data is provided, the constructed object will be empty, but still
 * valid.
 * @extends {jspb.Message}
 * @constructor
 */
proto.myservice.Reply = function(opt_data) {
  jspb.Message.initialize(this, opt_data, 0, -1, null, null);
};
goog.inherits(proto.myservice.Reply, jspb.Message);
if (goog.DEBUG && !COMPILED) {
  /**
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  proto.myservice.Reply.displayName = 'proto.myservice.Reply';
}



if (jspb.Message.GENERATE_TO_OBJECT) {
/**
 * Creates an object representation of this proto.
 * Field names that are reserved in JavaScript and will be renamed to pb_name.
 * Optional fields that are not set will be set to undefined.
 * To access a reserved field use, foo.pb_<name>, eg, foo.pb_default.
 * For the list of reserved names please see:
 *     net/proto2/compiler/js/internal/generator.cc#kKeyword.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_includeInstance Deprecated. whether to include the
 *     JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @return {!Object}
 */
proto.myservice.Request.prototype.toObject = function(opt_includeInstance) {
  return proto.myservice.Request.toObject(opt_includeInstance, this);
};


/**
 * Static version of the {@see toObject} method.
 * @param {boolean|undefined} includeInstance Deprecated. Whether to include
 *     the JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @param {!proto.myservice.Request} msg The msg instance to transform.
 * @return {!Object}
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.myservice.Request.toObject = function(includeInstance, msg) {
  var f, obj = {
    myFoo: jspb.Message.getBooleanFieldWithDefault(msg, 1, false),
    myBar: jspb.Message.getBooleanFieldWithDefault(msg, 2, false)
  };

  if (includeInstance) {
    obj.$jspbMessageInstance = msg;
  }
  return obj;
};
}


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @param {jspb.ByteSource} bytes The bytes to deserialize.
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Request}
 */
proto.myservice.Request.deserializeBinary = function(bytes) {
  var reader = new jspb.BinaryReader(bytes);
  var msg = new proto.myservice.Request;
  return proto.myservice.Request.deserializeBinaryFromReader(msg, reader);
};


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format) from the
 * given reader into the given message object.
 * @param {!proto.myservice.Request} msg The message object to deserialize into.
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryReader} reader The BinaryReader to use.
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Request}
 */
proto.myservice.Request.deserializeBinaryFromReader = function(msg, reader) {
  while (reader.nextField()) {
    if (reader.isEndGroup()) {
      break;
    }
    var field = reader.getFieldNumber();
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
      var value = /** @type {boolean} */ (reader.readBool());
      msg.setMyFoo(value);
      break;
    case 2:
      var value = /** @type {boolean} */ (reader.readBool());
      msg.setMyBar(value);
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipField();
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
};


/**
 * Serializes the message to binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.myservice.Request.prototype.serializeBinary = function() {
  var writer = new jspb.BinaryWriter();
  proto.myservice.Request.serializeBinaryToWriter(this, writer);
  return writer.getResultBuffer();
};


/**
 * Serializes the given message to binary data (in protobuf wire
 * format), writing to the given BinaryWriter.
 * @param {!proto.myservice.Request} message
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryWriter} writer
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.myservice.Request.serializeBinaryToWriter = function(message, writer) {
  var f = undefined;
  f = message.getMyFoo();
  if (f) {
    writer.writeBool(
      1,
      f
    );
  }
  f = message.getMyBar();
  if (f) {
    writer.writeBool(
      2,
      f
    );
  }
};


/**
 * optional bool my_foo = 1;
 * @return {boolean}
 */
proto.myservice.Request.prototype.getMyFoo = function() {
  return /** @type {boolean} */ (jspb.Message.getBooleanFieldWithDefault(this, 1, false));
};


/**
 * @param {boolean} value
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Request} returns this
 */
proto.myservice.Request.prototype.setMyFoo = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3BooleanField(this, 1, value);
};


/**
 * optional bool my_bar = 2;
 * @return {boolean}
 */
proto.myservice.Request.prototype.getMyBar = function() {
  return /** @type {boolean} */ (jspb.Message.getBooleanFieldWithDefault(this, 2, false));
};


/**
 * @param {boolean} value
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Request} returns this
 */
proto.myservice.Request.prototype.setMyBar = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3BooleanField(this, 2, value);
};





if (jspb.Message.GENERATE_TO_OBJECT) {
/**
 * Creates an object representation of this proto.
 * Field names that are reserved in JavaScript and will be renamed to pb_name.
 * Optional fields that are not set will be set to undefined.
 * To access a reserved field use, foo.pb_<name>, eg, foo.pb_default.
 * For the list of reserved names please see:
 *     net/proto2/compiler/js/internal/generator.cc#kKeyword.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_includeInstance Deprecated. whether to include the
 *     JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @return {!Object}
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.prototype.toObject = function(opt_includeInstance) {
  return proto.myservice.Reply.toObject(opt_includeInstance, this);
};


/**
 * Static version of the {@see toObject} method.
 * @param {boolean|undefined} includeInstance Deprecated. Whether to include
 *     the JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @param {!proto.myservice.Reply} msg The msg instance to transform.
 * @return {!Object}
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.toObject = function(includeInstance, msg) {
  var f, obj = {
    isSucceeded: jspb.Message.getBooleanFieldWithDefault(msg, 1, false)
  };

  if (includeInstance) {
    obj.$jspbMessageInstance = msg;
  }
  return obj;
};
}


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @param {jspb.ByteSource} bytes The bytes to deserialize.
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Reply}
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.deserializeBinary = function(bytes) {
  var reader = new jspb.BinaryReader(bytes);
  var msg = new proto.myservice.Reply;
  return proto.myservice.Reply.deserializeBinaryFromReader(msg, reader);
};


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format) from the
 * given reader into the given message object.
 * @param {!proto.myservice.Reply} msg The message object to deserialize into.
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryReader} reader The BinaryReader to use.
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Reply}
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.deserializeBinaryFromReader = function(msg, reader) {
  while (reader.nextField()) {
    if (reader.isEndGroup()) {
      break;
    }
    var field = reader.getFieldNumber();
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
      var value = /** @type {boolean} */ (reader.readBool());
      msg.setIsSucceeded(value);
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipField();
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
};


/**
 * Serializes the message to binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.prototype.serializeBinary = function() {
  var writer = new jspb.BinaryWriter();
  proto.myservice.Reply.serializeBinaryToWriter(this, writer);
  return writer.getResultBuffer();
};


/**
 * Serializes the given message to binary data (in protobuf wire
 * format), writing to the given BinaryWriter.
 * @param {!proto.myservice.Reply} message
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryWriter} writer
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.serializeBinaryToWriter = function(message, writer) {
  var f = undefined;
  f = message.getIsSucceeded();
  if (f) {
    writer.writeBool(
      1,
      f
    );
  }
};


/**
 * optional bool is_succeeded = 1;
 * @return {boolean}
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.prototype.getIsSucceeded = function() {
  return /** @type {boolean} */ (jspb.Message.getBooleanFieldWithDefault(this, 1, false));
};


/**
 * @param {boolean} value
 * @return {!proto.myservice.Reply} returns this
 */
proto.myservice.Reply.prototype.setIsSucceeded = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3BooleanField(this, 1, value);
};


goog.object.extend(exports, proto.myservice);
```

#### Dart

With the same treatment as above

```sh
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-dart="$HOME/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart" --dart_out=grpc:"${DST_DIR}" -I"${SRC_DIR}" -I"$IncludeDir" my.proto
```

my.pbgrpc.dart

```dart
///
//  Generated code. Do not modify.
//  source: my.proto
//
// @dart = 2.12
// ignore_for_file: annotate_overrides,camel_case_types,unnecessary_const,non_constant_identifier_names,library_prefixes,unused_import,unused_shown_name,return_of_invalid_type,unnecessary_this,prefer_final_fields

import 'dart:async' as $async;

import 'dart:core' as $core;

import 'package:grpc/service_api.dart' as $grpc;
import 'my.pb.dart' as $0;
export 'my.pb.dart';

class MyserviceClient extends $grpc.Client {
  static final _$myService = $grpc.ClientMethod<$0.Request, $0.Reply>(
      '/myservice.Myservice/MyService',
      ($0.Request value) => value.writeToBuffer(),
      ($core.List<$core.int> value) => $0.Reply.fromBuffer(value));

  MyserviceClient($grpc.ClientChannel channel,
      {$grpc.CallOptions? options,
      $core.Iterable<$grpc.ClientInterceptor>? interceptors})
      : super(channel, options: options, interceptors: interceptors);

  $grpc.ResponseFuture<$0.Reply> myService($0.Request request,
      {$grpc.CallOptions? options}) {
    return $createUnaryCall(_$myService, request, options: options);
  }
}

abstract class MyserviceServiceBase extends $grpc.Service {
  $core.String get $name => 'myservice.Myservice';

  MyserviceServiceBase() {
    $addMethod($grpc.ServiceMethod<$0.Request, $0.Reply>(
        'MyService',
        myService_Pre,
        false,
        false,
        ($core.List<$core.int> value) => $0.Request.fromBuffer(value),
        ($0.Reply value) => value.writeToBuffer()));
  }

  $async.Future<$0.Reply> myService_Pre(
      $grpc.ServiceCall call, $async.Future<$0.Request> request) async {
    return myService(call, await request);
  }

  $async.Future<$0.Reply> myService($grpc.ServiceCall call, $0.Request request);
}
```

my.pb.dart

```dart
///
//  Generated code. Do not modify.
//  source: my.proto
//
// @dart = 2.12
// ignore_for_file: annotate_overrides,camel_case_types,unnecessary_const,non_constant_identifier_names,library_prefixes,unused_import,unused_shown_name,return_of_invalid_type,unnecessary_this,prefer_final_fields

import 'dart:core' as $core;

import 'package:protobuf/protobuf.dart' as $pb;

class Request extends $pb.GeneratedMessage {
  static final $pb.BuilderInfo _i = $pb.BuilderInfo(const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_message_names') ? '' : 'Request', package: const $pb.PackageName(const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_message_names') ? '' : 'myservice'), createEmptyInstance: create)
    ..aOB(1, const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_field_names') ? '' : 'myFoo')
    ..aOB(2, const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_field_names') ? '' : 'myBar')
    ..hasRequiredFields = false
  ;

  Request._() : super();
  factory Request({
    $core.bool? myFoo,
    $core.bool? myBar,
  }) {
    final _result = create();
    if (myFoo != null) {
      _result.myFoo = myFoo;
    }
    if (myBar != null) {
      _result.myBar = myBar;
    }
    return _result;
  }
  factory Request.fromBuffer($core.List<$core.int> i, [$pb.ExtensionRegistry r = $pb.ExtensionRegistry.EMPTY]) => create()..mergeFromBuffer(i, r);
  factory Request.fromJson($core.String i, [$pb.ExtensionRegistry r = $pb.ExtensionRegistry.EMPTY]) => create()..mergeFromJson(i, r);
  @$core.Deprecated(
  'Using this can add significant overhead to your binary. '
  'Use [GeneratedMessageGenericExtensions.deepCopy] instead. '
  'Will be removed in next major version')
  Request clone() => Request()..mergeFromMessage(this);
  @$core.Deprecated(
  'Using this can add significant overhead to your binary. '
  'Use [GeneratedMessageGenericExtensions.rebuild] instead. '
  'Will be removed in next major version')
  Request copyWith(void Function(Request) updates) => super.copyWith((message) => updates(message as Request)) as Request; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  $pb.BuilderInfo get info_ => _i;
  @$core.pragma('dart2js:noInline')
  static Request create() => Request._();
  Request createEmptyInstance() => create();
  static $pb.PbList<Request> createRepeated() => $pb.PbList<Request>();
  @$core.pragma('dart2js:noInline')
  static Request getDefault() => _defaultInstance ??= $pb.GeneratedMessage.$_defaultFor<Request>(create);
  static Request? _defaultInstance;

  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  $core.bool get myFoo => $_getBF(0);
  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  set myFoo($core.bool v) { $_setBool(0, v); }
  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  $core.bool hasMyFoo() => $_has(0);
  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  void clearMyFoo() => clearField(1);

  @$pb.TagNumber(2)
  $core.bool get myBar => $_getBF(1);
  @$pb.TagNumber(2)
  set myBar($core.bool v) { $_setBool(1, v); }
  @$pb.TagNumber(2)
  $core.bool hasMyBar() => $_has(1);
  @$pb.TagNumber(2)
  void clearMyBar() => clearField(2);
}

class Reply extends $pb.GeneratedMessage {
  static final $pb.BuilderInfo _i = $pb.BuilderInfo(const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_message_names') ? '' : 'Reply', package: const $pb.PackageName(const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_message_names') ? '' : 'myservice'), createEmptyInstance: create)
    ..aOB(1, const $core.bool.fromEnvironment('protobuf.omit_field_names') ? '' : 'isSucceeded')
    ..hasRequiredFields = false
  ;

  Reply._() : super();
  factory Reply({
    $core.bool? isSucceeded,
  }) {
    final _result = create();
    if (isSucceeded != null) {
      _result.isSucceeded = isSucceeded;
    }
    return _result;
  }
  factory Reply.fromBuffer($core.List<$core.int> i, [$pb.ExtensionRegistry r = $pb.ExtensionRegistry.EMPTY]) => create()..mergeFromBuffer(i, r);
  factory Reply.fromJson($core.String i, [$pb.ExtensionRegistry r = $pb.ExtensionRegistry.EMPTY]) => create()..mergeFromJson(i, r);
  @$core.Deprecated(
  'Using this can add significant overhead to your binary. '
  'Use [GeneratedMessageGenericExtensions.deepCopy] instead. '
  'Will be removed in next major version')
  Reply clone() => Reply()..mergeFromMessage(this);
  @$core.Deprecated(
  'Using this can add significant overhead to your binary. '
  'Use [GeneratedMessageGenericExtensions.rebuild] instead. '
  'Will be removed in next major version')
  Reply copyWith(void Function(Reply) updates) => super.copyWith((message) => updates(message as Reply)) as Reply; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  $pb.BuilderInfo get info_ => _i;
  @$core.pragma('dart2js:noInline')
  static Reply create() => Reply._();
  Reply createEmptyInstance() => create();
  static $pb.PbList<Reply> createRepeated() => $pb.PbList<Reply>();
  @$core.pragma('dart2js:noInline')
  static Reply getDefault() => _defaultInstance ??= $pb.GeneratedMessage.$_defaultFor<Reply>(create);
  static Reply? _defaultInstance;

  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  $core.bool get isSucceeded => $_getBF(0);
  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  set isSucceeded($core.bool v) { $_setBool(0, v); }
  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  $core.bool hasIsSucceeded() => $_has(0);
  @$pb.TagNumber(1)
  void clearIsSucceeded() => clearField(1);
}
```

### Comparison

If we compare the following generated entities

- Service class name
- Service method name
- Request field names
- Reply field names

Here are the results

#### Python

```
Myservice
MyService
my_foo
my_bar
is_succeeded
```

#### Node.js

```js
MyserviceService
myService
accessor: getMyFoo()
accessor: getMyBar()
accessor: getIsSucceeded()
```

#### Dart

```dart
MyserviceServiceBase
myService
myFoo
myBar
isSucceeded
```

### Question

Although these naming schemes seem to cater to the language-specific convention,
the differences between them caused some maintenance issues.

I wonder if there is a way to ensure an identical casing treatment across all these languages, and possibly all supported languages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code generation [plugins](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.plugin.pb) have complete freedom to generate whatever code they want. Usually, they try to follow the language's conventions. You'd need to have controls for each language, and most won't provide it.

What are the [actual maintenance issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that you are facing? Perhaps there is some other way of solving them.

Comment: Regarding the issues, we'd love to have a unified naming convention across all languages. Stuff like NodeJS's accessors, as opposed to direct access to variables, makes us have to abstract the differences away language by language. I guess you confirmed that level of complexity then. Thanks!